# In Visio, how do I create a chart with coordinates throughtout time

Tags: charts, microsoft-visio

I have these data (from MSSQL, that I converted into Access/Excel) on a moving object in a defined space

```
x   y           time
0   0   07/04/2014 08:48:07
5   5   07/04/2014 16:35:25
6   4   07/04/2014 16:35:25
3   6   07/04/2014 16:44:14
6   6   07/04/2014 16:44:39
3   5   07/04/2014 16:45:45
6   4   07/04/2014 16:47:03
```

I'd like to create a scatter chart with a connecting line going from 1 to 2 to 3 to ...100 every 2 seconds.  It's suppose to look like a spaghetti diagram.

Google has it working just ok but it's unstable...
[Google motion chart](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oxWCrkuzNtI)
But that is for their spreadsheet.

Comment: Where does the data come from? Why Visio? This would be a piece of cake with Excel. You could embed the Excel chart into Visio.

Comment: because in Visio, we can create a floor easier, with doors, windows, etc. any link to how to do it in Excel?

Comment: I noticed that you unaccepted my answer.  Did something not work for you? Or is there another problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options to do this, one with Excel (which I prefer) and one in Visio alone, but generally the process is the same.  Using Excel:

1. Create a scatter chart with your data.
2. Create a square grid using your rows/columns.
3. Align your chart's axis to the grid so that your horizontal and vertical axis are scaled to the appropriate room size.
4. Format as desired.
5. Copy the chart.
6. Switch to Visio.
7. Paste your chart as an Picture (enhanced metafile), this produces the best resolution in my experience.
8. Align your chart over your floor plan.

Using Visio:

1. Insert a chart.
2. Select your chart, right click and choose Chart Object > Open.
3. Change the default chart to a Scatter Type.
4. Modify the data to your spatial data.
5. Format the chart as desired.
6. Align your chart over your floor plan.

Using Visio doesn't require you to copy/paste your chart, but you'll be stuck using the Microsoft Graph tool, which I think is inferior to Excel's built-in charting capabilities.  Also, you'll have to move your data from Access/Excel to MS Graph, which could be cumbersome.  Finally, since you're documenting movement, Excel has better formatting options, such as adding arrow end caps.

Here's a sample (in each, I left the axis labels on for reference, but you can turn those off with either solution).

[image]

Comment: in visio mode, i can't find the way to import the data into the chart.

Comment: I don't have it in front of me, bit I don't think you can import data into MS Graph, you may be able to copy/paste.

Comment: @dav, I hope you're not an architect or builder. The door should be hinged on the other side. It should open up into the room, not into the wall. I see this mistake in many cheap housing projects.

Comment: @teylyn, good catch. No worries, I'm not involved in the building trades at all.  I am guilty of grabbing the Visio default and not changing anything else-but no excuse for not paying attention to details!

Answer (score 0):

You could consider creating a polyline in visio, avoiding use of excel altogether (unless your data is storend in excel rather than a text file or so). Times updates could be managende a small macro that takes the existing polyline string and appendage it with the newly gained x-y's.